# Input command with system() and sleep()

Tags: c++, cmd, sleep

Is there a way to use system() and ask for the code to wait a few seconds?

I have been trying something like:

```
system("MyCmd");
sleep(8000);
```

However, `sleep()` terminates "MyCmd" execution.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What code? And how can `sleep()` terminate the execution? It's probably because the program terminates, which ends `MyCmd` with it.

Answer (score 1):

> However, sleep() terminates "MyCmd" execution.

No. The `sleep()` expression doesn't terminate the child process created with the `system()` call, the expressions

```
system("MyCmd");
sleep(8000);
```

will just be executed sequentially.

---

What you can do is to call [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) to create a child process, call `sleep()` in the parent process, and [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html) the child process, if it's still running after the parent process awakes:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    // child process
    execl ("/bin/MyCmd", "MyCmd", (char *)0);
}
else if (pid > 0) {
    // parent process
    sleep(8000);
    kill(pid,SIGKILL);
}
else {
    // fork failed
    printf("fork() failed!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Or you can use threads (also under systems, where `fork()` is not available, e.g. Windows).

Comment: @axalis You won't have that level of control (`kill()`) if you're using `std::thread`.

Comment: But the thread running the command can be "killed" (terminated), or? Another possibility under Windows could be CreateProcess, where you can get the handle of the new process which can be killed.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, sleep() doesn't terminate. There was actually a bug in my code. However, your answer did anticipate what my next problem would be.

Comment: @axalis Unfortunately there's nothing like `std::thread::kill()`, it's currently not a portable feature it seems.

Comment: @Arthur Please don't ask your _next problem_ here, but in a separate question.

Comment: I guess the problem actually was that the command terminated immediately by itself (`system()` normally doesn't return until the command completes), so the sleeping is actually the "next problem" :)

Comment: @axalis Could well be, that OP misunderstood these commands aren't executed asynchronously.

Comment: Yes indeed. To be honest the problem lied completely outside of the code. Took me some time to figure this one out. And no, I am not going to ask another question here, axalis got it. Thank you both very much!